# Mean.js angularjs querying the mongodb database

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mean

I know this is a stupid question, but I'm missing something and I'm lost.

I have created a new project using 'yo meanjs' thus creating the standard scaffolding.

From the public side of the application I am trying to search the Users for a user based not on their id but rather their email address.

Some how I need to write the query using Users.get or Users.query but I cannot find an example of how to do this. Do I have to create new controllers/routes on the app side?

On the public side I've tried many different things like:

```
var user = Users.query({
    email: 'bob@this.com'
});
```

I can't seem to see the forest through the beautiful trees right now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the answer was a bit more complicated.  This is working, although there may be a better way to do it.

I had to create a new function in one of the app user controllers:

```
exports.userByEmail = function(req, res, next, email) {
  console.log('userByEmail ' + email);
  User.findOne({
    email: email
  }).exec(function(err, user) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    if (!user) return next(new Error('Failed to load User with email ' + email));
    res.json(user);
    next();
  });
};
```

Next, I had to create a new route:

```
app.route('/users/email/:emailAddr').get(users.me);
app.param('emailAddr', users.userByEmail);
```

Then I called it with a $htttp.get:

```
$http.get('/users/email/' + newEmail).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // do something useful with data
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.error = 'Problem finding a user with that email';
    });
```

The problem stemmed from my inability to use one of the existing CRUD calls to send a query json object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use findOne().

```
User.findOne({email: req.body.email}, function(err, user){
   //...
   callback(err);
});
```